# Map is not showing in app installed from playstore

Tags: android, android-mapview

I get strange problem. I app is available on play store. When app is install from eclipse, map is showing. While at same time, if app is install from play store, map is not seen. I do not know where i make mistake. Please help.

Link to app - https://play.google.com/stor/apps/details?id=netleon.sansar.childsafeapp

Comment: Have you generate new API Key with your keystore?

Comment: No, I am using my old keystore.

Comment: So what you waiting for??? generate a New key with your own Keystore

Comment: While uploading app with new keystore to play store got error- uploading failed. What to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Eclipse you have a debug keystore, for google play store you have a different key store. You api key needs to match the keystore you have used to sign the application.